# Выравнивание встроенного SVG с текстом

Tags: html, css, svg

У меня есть следующий [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bh2hou48/2/), где SVG помещается слева от некоторого текста внутри кнопки. Я хотел бы, чтобы SVG был встроен в текст, чтобы он располагался вертикально на кнопке.

Я думал об использовании следующих методов:

- Однако использование `line-height`, похоже, не работает.
- При использовании `margin-top:`  все содержимое кнопки перемещается
  вниз.

Что я могу сделать, чтобы выровнять SVG с текстом?

```css
    button {
        font-family:'Texta-Regular', sans-serif;
        font-size: 2.7em;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        display: block;
        margin: 2em auto;
        padding: .3em 2em;
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkitborder-radius: 5px;
        outline: none;
        background-color: #dd4b39;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .icon {
        width: 1em;
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<button>
    <svg version="1.1" fill="#fff" class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 96.828 96.827" xml:space="preserve">
        <path d="M62.617,0H39.525c-10.29,0-17.413,2.256-23.824,7.552c-5.042,4.35-8.051,10.672-8.051,16.912c0,9.614,7.33,19.831,20.913,19.831c1.306,0,2.752-0.134,4.028-0.253l-0.188,0.457c-0.546,1.308-1.063,2.542-1.063,4.468c0,3.75,1.809,6.063,3.558,8.298l0.22,0.283l-0.391,0.027c-5.609,0.384-16.049,1.1-23.675,5.787c-9.007,5.355-9.707,13.145-9.707,15.404c0,8.988,8.376,18.06,27.09,18.06c21.76,0,33.146-12.005,33.146-23.863c0.002-8.771-5.141-13.101-10.6-17.698l-4.605-3.582c-1.423-1.179-3.195-2.646-3.195-5.364c0-2.672,1.772-4.436,3.336-5.992l0.163-0.165c4.973-3.917,10.609-8.358,10.609-17.964c0-9.658-6.035-14.649-8.937-17.048h7.663c0.094,0,0.188-0.026,0.266-0.077l6.601-4.15c0.188-0.119,0.276-0.348,0.214-0.562C63.037,0.147,62.839,0,62.617,0z M34.614,91.535c-13.264,0-22.176-6.195-22.176-15.416c0-6.021,3.645-10.396,10.824-12.997c5.749-1.935,13.17-2.031,13.244-2.031c1.257,0,1.889,0,2.893,0.126c9.281,6.605,13.743,10.073,13.743,16.678C53.141,86.309,46.041,91.535,34.614,91.535z M34.489,40.756c-11.132,0-15.752-14.633-15.752-22.468c0-3.984,0.906-7.042,2.77-9.351c2.023-2.531,5.487-4.166,8.825-4.166c10.221,0,15.873,13.738,15.873,23.233c0,1.498,0,6.055-3.148,9.22C40.94,39.337,37.497,40.756,34.489,40.756z" />
        <path d="M94.982,45.223H82.814V33.098c0-0.276-0.225-0.5-0.5-0.5H77.08c-0.276,0-0.5,0.224-0.5,0.5v12.125H64.473c-0.276,0-0.5,0.224-0.5,0.5v5.304c0,0.275,0.224,0.5,0.5,0.5H76.58V63.73c0,0.275,0.224,0.5,0.5,0.5h5.234c0.275,0,0.5-0.225,0.5-0.5V51.525h12.168c0.276,0,0.5-0.223,0.5-0.5v-5.302C95.482,45.446,95.259,45.223,94.982,45.223z" />
    </svg>Sign In with Google</button>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Aligning an SVG inline with text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32030276/7394871) от участника  [@Pav Sidhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2961662/pav-sidhu).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/32030276/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Если `vertical-align` не обеспечивает достаточно тонкого позиционирования для вас, вы можете попробовать настроить относительное позиционирование значка с помощью `position: relative ;`.

```
.icon {
    ...
    position: relative;
    top: 0.15em;
}
```

Если вы используете значения `em` для позиционирования, то это должно позволить классу работать с любым размером шрифта.

```css
  button {
        font-family:'Texta-Regular', sans-serif;
        font-size: 2.7em;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        display: block;
        margin: 2em auto;
        padding: .3em 2em;
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkitborder-radius: 5px;
        outline: none;
        background-color: #dd4b39;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .icon {
        width: 1em;
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 40px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0.15em;
    }
```

```html
<button>
    <svg version="1.1" fill="#fff" class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 96.828 96.827" xml:space="preserve">
        <path d="M62.617,0H39.525c-10.29,0-17.413,2.256-23.824,7.552c-5.042,4.35-8.051,10.672-8.051,16.912c0,9.614,7.33,19.831,20.913,19.831c1.306,0,2.752-0.134,4.028-0.253l-0.188,0.457c-0.546,1.308-1.063,2.542-1.063,4.468c0,3.75,1.809,6.063,3.558,8.298l0.22,0.283l-0.391,0.027c-5.609,0.384-16.049,1.1-23.675,5.787c-9.007,5.355-9.707,13.145-9.707,15.404c0,8.988,8.376,18.06,27.09,18.06c21.76,0,33.146-12.005,33.146-23.863c0.002-8.771-5.141-13.101-10.6-17.698l-4.605-3.582c-1.423-1.179-3.195-2.646-3.195-5.364c0-2.672,1.772-4.436,3.336-5.992l0.163-0.165c4.973-3.917,10.609-8.358,10.609-17.964c0-9.658-6.035-14.649-8.937-17.048h7.663c0.094,0,0.188-0.026,0.266-0.077l6.601-4.15c0.188-0.119,0.276-0.348,0.214-0.562C63.037,0.147,62.839,0,62.617,0z M34.614,91.535c-13.264,0-22.176-6.195-22.176-15.416c0-6.021,3.645-10.396,10.824-12.997c5.749-1.935,13.17-2.031,13.244-2.031c1.257,0,1.889,0,2.893,0.126c9.281,6.605,13.743,10.073,13.743,16.678C53.141,86.309,46.041,91.535,34.614,91.535z M34.489,40.756c-11.132,0-15.752-14.633-15.752-22.468c0-3.984,0.906-7.042,2.77-9.351c2.023-2.531,5.487-4.166,8.825-4.166c10.221,0,15.873,13.738,15.873,23.233c0,1.498,0,6.055-3.148,9.22C40.94,39.337,37.497,40.756,34.489,40.756z" />
        <path d="M94.982,45.223H82.814V33.098c0-0.276-0.225-0.5-0.5-0.5H77.08c-0.276,0-0.5,0.224-0.5,0.5v12.125H64.473c-0.276,0-0.5,0.224-0.5,0.5v5.304c0,0.275,0.224,0.5,0.5,0.5H76.58V63.73c0,0.275,0.224,0.5,0.5,0.5h5.234c0.275,0,0.5-0.225,0.5-0.5V51.525h12.168c0.276,0,0.5-0.223,0.5-0.5v-5.302C95.482,45.446,95.259,45.223,94.982,45.223z" />
    </svg>Sign In with Google</button>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32032259/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>